# Send data to to another kdb process randomly

Tags: kdb

I have 3 q processes running

1. RDB
2. Parse from RDB and send appropriate data to 3rd-process
3. accepts data

Constraints:

- Process 3 can only accept **500 rows of data every day**
- Have to make sure those 500 data rows are also sent to this process **randomly throughout one day**

I want to write a function that sits on process 2 and is called every 5sec (`\t 5000`), this function pulls data from RDB and then sends data to process-3 randomly throughout the day while making sure I am not violating the 500 rows of data limit for one day. Once I have sent 500, `.z.ts` doesn't get any data from process 1 and won't send any to process 3. Rinse and repeat every day.

```
h1: hopen `::9090;   /connect to process 1
h3: hopen `::9091;   /connect to process 3

fetchfunc{[]
 data:: h1"select[500] from table1";   / 500 data constraint
 flag::1;
};

sendfunc{[]
 while[flag=1; 
  h3(insert, `tab2;data[counter]);    / tab2 table on process 3 (HOW TO INSERT RANDOMLY!) 
  counter: counter+1;
  if[counter=500; flag::0]; 
  ];
};


.z.ts{[]
 $[flag=0; fetchfun[]; sendfun[]];
};
```

Comment: This is very vague, and there isn't really a question here. Have you tried making this function? You say that data is parsed and sent to a 3rd process, however there is no indication of how the data is parsed. 

It is unlikely anyone on SO will simply write you a function with nothing to work from, please a minimum working example and an expected result, and also any attempt and creating this function you want.

Comment: Sorry, Eliot. I have updated it with my basic code. Not sure how to insert into process 3 table randomly and space out that randomness thought out one day

Comment: @karanshah Could you please elaborate more on your 'randomness' requirement. Your sample code fetches first 500 rows from `table1` and inserts them into `tab2` in a very deterministic way, I don't see any randomness there.